# Insert a vertical line along the text on the left

Tags: formatting

In 'article' environment, with the following code (without preambles):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\fontfamily{lmss}{\LARGE{Basic and Useful Tools in Python}}}
\end{center}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4em}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\section{Summations}
{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont
Codes within this section will involve summation in some way or another.
}
{\subsection{\small{Sum of first $n$ natural numbers}}}
{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont
Using the range command, we will have the following:}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
In [1]
def sum_of_the_first_n_positive_integers(n):
    output = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        output = output + i
    return output

In [2] (Example)
sum_of_the_first_n_positive_integers(10)
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{0.3cm}

{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont
An alternative method for this question will be simply using the summation formula:}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
In [1]
def sum_of_the_first_n_positive_integers_v2(n):
    return n*(n+1)//2

In [2] (Example)
sum_of_the_first_n_positive_integers_v2(10)
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\end{document}
```

Will give us the following pdf:
[image]

I'm wondering how I can insert a vertical line besides the codes like so:
[image]

I'm using the package 'listings' to insert python codes into latex. I tried using warpfig and inserting an image of a straight line, but that did not turned out too well.

Comment: The `framed` package defines a `leftbar`  environment, which can break across pages (and also `framed` and `shaded` environments, with the same property).

Comment: The tcolorbox package is even fancier

Comment: You can add the option `frame={l}` (left) to the listing environment, as in `\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,frame={l}]`.

Comment: Off-topic: You may find it useful to learn about the `\textsf` command. For instance, it would let you simplify `{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont ...}` to `\textsf{...}`. (I'm assuming the preamble of your document, which you've chosen not to show, loads the `lmodern` package.) And, for crying out loud, please replace `{\subsection{\small{Sum of first $n$ natural numbers}}}` with `\subsection{\small Sum of first $n$ natural numbers}`. BTW, speaking for myself, it's dreadful to typeset the number of the subsection header in `\large` and the text itself in `\small`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JuanCastaño Just curious, is there a way to modify the frames?

Comment: If you want more than to add borders, i.e. colors, headers, etc. I'd go for the `tcolorbox` package, as daleif suggests. Take a look at the manual, specially at libraries `listings`, `listingsutf8` and `minted`.